# OSX text shortcuts, that work on terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Any OSX feature (or accepted hack) that allows me to conveniently type a long string, but that would also work on terminal?

Something similar to `settings > keyboard > text` where I can set "replace: brb, with: be right back".

I have very few strings I want to use, so a key combination might be a good alternative. e.g. Command+F2 types "be right back".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this natively on OSX settings. I've been using atext app to set these expansion triggers in terminal.

It's a very powerful app. You can set a string to expand automatically in any app, or even specify certain apps.
You can also specify if strings should expand automatically or only when followed by additional modifier keys

$5 for mac: https://www.trankynam.com/atext/